# Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() ..?

Tags: php, json

Im trying to use json with php and i keep getting the error

> > PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_encode()

I am using php version 5.3.6 and on phpinfo(); nothing mentions json. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try installing: http://pecl.php.net/package/json

Comment: @stslavik When i try installing it says ` cannot install: doesn't work with PHP version : 5 (Doesn't support PHP 5 52)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason your PHP was compiled without JSON. Either:

- Recompile it
- Install a package
- Use a function that emulates json_encode, which can be found in the comments section of http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Debian/Ubuntu, try:

```
apt-get install php5-json
```

and then

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

This will install the extension (this works on PHP 5.5.3).

Answer (score 2):

try in shell (assuming you are using linux),
otherwise refer to `phpinfo();`

```
php -i | grep json
```

example

```
php -i | grep json
json
json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

There is an interesting comment on the docs
http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.requirements.php

> If you're not seeing the json functions on 5.2.0 or newer, make sure php wasn't compiled with --disable-json

Comment: I keep seeing this around.. where do i run --disable-json?

Comment: you should delete this question :)

Comment: Cant if theres already answers :/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved on Centos 8

Used @ajreal's answer above ([Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() ..?](https://serverfault.com/questions/308653/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-json-encode/308655#308655)) to find if it's enabled. If it's not, do this:

```
sudo dnf install php-json
```